# Backbone Collection running a method on the `add` event getting: "TypeError: obj[implementation] is not a function"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

My desired goal is to have the console log the title of each post (grabbed from my API). However I appear to be doing *something* wrong, specifically I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: obj[implementation] is not a function` on the line `this.listenTo(PostCollection, 'add', this.render);` -- I want to listen to any additions to the PostCollection and fire the event to fetch all of the objects from the API. Here's the error stack:

```
Uncaught TypeError: obj[implementation] is not a function
_.each.Events.(anonymous function) @ backbone.js:225
Backbone.View.extend.initialize @ test.js:61
Backbone.View @ backbone.js:1001
child @ backbone.js:1566
(anonymous function) @ test.js:70
(anonymous function) @ test.js:72
```

API Response: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c270f9ca9befa054ecef

My backbone code:

```
(function ($) {
    var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: 'http://api.xxx.com/wp-json/posts',
        defaults: {
            id: null,
            status: '',
            title: ''

        }
    });

    var PostCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: Post,
        url: 'http://api.xxx.com/wp-json/posts',
        sync: function (method, model, options) {
            return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
        },

        parse: function (response) {

            if (response) {
                var listSource = [];
                _.each(response, function (element, index, list) {


                    listSource.push(new Post({
                        id: element.id,
                        title: element.title,
                        status: element.status

                    }));


                });
                return listSource;
            } else {
                alert('Error...');
                return [];
            }
        }


    });


    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#app',


        render: function () {
            console.log(this.model.get('title'));

        },

        initialize: function () {


            this.listenTo(PostCollection, 'add', this.render);

            PostCollection.fetch();
        }

    });



    new AppView();

})(jQuery);
```

My HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-framework="backbonejs">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>FOO</title>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app"></div>


        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
        <script src="js/test.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your collection. You are trying to listenTo and Fetch on a class, whereas you should be doing so on an instance of the class.

```
 this.collection = new PostCollection();

 this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);

 this.collection.fetch();
```

I couldn't check you code since I don't have the endpoint, but it looks like your console.log in the render function won't work either. First of all, you don't have a model defined. I presume you want to print the title of the post that was just added. One way to do that would be to do:

```
 render: function () {
     console.log(this.collection.last().get('title'));
 },
```